Test Failing with Composite Key in Spring Boot 3.3.x but Passing in Spring Boot 3.2.x
I'm experiencing an issue where a test involving a composite key in Spring Data JPA is passing in Spring Boot 3.2.0 but failing in Spring Boot 3.3.2.
Problem Description:
I have a ProductRating entity with a composite key (ProductRatingId) that combines CustomerId and ProductId. The test works fine in Spring Boot 3.2.0 but fails in Spring Boot 3.3.2.
In Spring Boot 3.2.0, the test works as expected. But, in Spring Boot 3.3.2 the same test fails.
@Test
public void testCreateProductRating() {
    // Create and save a Product
    Product product = Product.builder()
            .name("Test Product")
            .build();
    product = productRepository.save(product);

    // Create and save a Customer
    Customer customer = Customer.builder()
            .name("Test Customer")
            .build();
    customer = customerRepository.save(customer);

    // Create a ProductRating
    ProductRating productRating = ProductRating.builder()
            .id(new ProductRatingId()) // Fails in Spring Boot 3.3.x
            .customer(customer)
            .product(product)
            .rating(10)
            .build();

    productRatingRepository.save(productRating);

    // Assert that the rating is saved correctly
    assertThat(productRating).isNotNull();
    assertThat(productRating.getId().getProductId()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(productRating.getId().getCustomerId()).isNotNull();
    assertThat(productRating.getRating()).isEqualTo(10);
    assertThat(productRating.getCustomer().getName()).isEqualTo("Test Customer");
    assertThat(productRating.getProduct().getName()).isEqualTo("Test Product");
}


Investigation:
I found that explicitly setting the customerId and productId in the ProductRatingId before saving resolves the issue, but this wasn't necessary in Spring Boot 3.2.x.
It seems like something changed in how Hibernate or Spring Data JPA handles composite keys between these versions.
I also found that the test passes in Spring Boot 3.3.2 if I reassign the ProductRating entity after the save operation, like this:
productRating = productRatingRepository.save(productRating);

With this adjustment, the test behaves as expected, and the customerId and productId fields are correctly populated in the ProductRatingId.
Question:
Is this behavior expected in Spring Boot 3.3.x? Were there any changes in Hibernate or Spring Data JPA between these versions that could explain this issue?
Additional Information:

You can see the actual test results in GitHub Actions:

Tests passing with Spring Boot 3.2.0
Tests failing with Spring Boot 3.3.2


GitHub Repository

